# Ubuntu works only when started in recovery mode

Tags: boot, login, recovery-mode, 21.04

I'm running Ubuntu 21.04 on Honor Magicbook and it worked fine until recently. Now, every time I start Ubuntu I get to log in screen, but after submitting my password I only see a mouse pointer on a all-purple background -- nothing else happens afterwards.

I've found a hack which allows me to run the system as usual. In the GRUB startup menu I'm selecting "Ubuntu (recovery)" option and then just select "resume: Resume normal boot" option from the recovery script menu. That way the system boots and works fine. But after the next system restart, if I select normal Ubuntu booting option I'll get the same issue again.

I've tried to run "dpkg: Repair broken packages" and "fsck: Check all the file systems" from Ubuntu recovery menu, but it didn't help to fix the issue.

Not sure when it had actually started behaving like that. It might be after some software install or update, or maybe it was caused by forced shutdown while there was an active Ubuntu user session.

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
Have just realized that in recovery mode I get Ubuntu running on X11 window system, whereas normal booting mode starts Wayland. So the problem must be related to Wayland.

Comment: Review your logs, which will happily tell you if you are really encountering Wayland errors or not. If so, please file a bug report.

Comment: @user535733 which logs should we collect?